# how to find the sum of list indexes which are given in the sublists of another list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, set, sublist

i have given a list

`myLIST=[34 , 54 , 65 , 76 , 88 , 23 , 56 , 76 , 43]`

and a list with the index numbers of myLIST in sublist (assume myLIST starts from index 1)

`indexLIST=[{1,2,3} , {4,5,7} , {6,8,9}]`

my task is to add the indexes of myLIST according to the sublists of indexLIST

`[{34+54+65} , {76,88,23} , {56,76,43}]`

```
res=[153 ,187 , 175]
```

Note: the sublists of indexLIST are python sets

Comment: What did you try? Is there any problem with the code you showed us?

Comment: i didn;t solve this..as i am stuck here...i have just two lists one is myLIST and other one is indexLIST

Answer (score 1):

So first of all there is either a mistake in your `indexLIST` (set 2 should be `{4, 5, 6}` and set 3 `{7, 8, 9}`) or your `res` (which with the given `indexLIST` is `[153, 220, 142]`) otherwise you can just do something like this:

```
res: list[int] = list()
for set in indexLIST:
    tmp = 0
    for idx in set:
        tmp += myLIST[idx - 1]
    res.append(tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to iterate over the sets of indices in `index_list` and then map these sets to the values of `my_list`. With `sum()` I then can compute the sum of each list of values:

```
my_list=[34 , 54 , 65 , 76 , 88 , 23 , 56 , 76 , 43]
index_list=[{1,2,3} , {4,5,7} , {6,8,9}]

result = [sum(map(lambda x: my_list[x-1], d)) for d in index_list]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[153, 220, 142]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myLIST=[34 , 54 , 65 , 76 , 88 , 23 , 56 , 76 , 43]
indexLIST=[{1,2,3} , {4,5,6} , {7,8,9}]

from pprint import pprint
pprint([sum([myLIST[j-1] for j in i])for i in indexLIST])
```

Result:

```
[153, 220, 142]
```

P.S.

This type of indexing which you're trying to achive could be very fragile, e.g. what if the index, which you're giving doesn't exist in your list ->IndexError ...?

Comment: Not much different from the approach above ...